# how to publish second, third, or fourth item from an observation

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I had a multiple items in one observation in a data frame, can I publish the second or third item as stand alone piece of data?  For example, let's say my data frame looks as follows:

```
Name          State_of_Business
Company X     NJ,PA,DE
```

and let say I want to print state_of_business with the following view code:

```
  <body>
    <% @firm.each do |firm| %>
    <tr>
        <td> <b>State 1</b> <%= firm.state_of_business %> </td>
        <td> <b>State 2</b> <%= firm.state_of_business %> </td>
        <td> <b>State 3</b> <%= firm.state_of_business %> </td>
    <tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
  </body>
```

How could I get it to list the following:

State 1: NJ

State 2: PA

State 3: DE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<% @firm.each do |firm| %>
<tr>
    <% firm.state_of_business.split(',').each_with_index do |state, index| %>
        <td> <b>State <%= index + 1 %></b> <%= state %> </td>
    <% end %>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

**PS**: Don't forget to add the opening/closing tags, `</table>` have no matching `<table>`.

Comment: thanks, @lunr.  I'm receiving the follower syntax error and can't seem to fix it:   syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end '.freeze; firm.state.split(',').each_with_index |state, index| ^

Comment: how could I limit the number of items I publish.  For example, if I wanted to publish the first 5 items, how might i go about doing that?

Comment: meaning, I would only publish 5 and stop there.  I tried the following code but couldn't get it to work: <td> <b>State <%= index(1..2) %></b> <%= state %> </td>

Comment: You can do `firm.state_of_business.split(',')[0..4].each_with_index....`

Comment: thanks again.  I had the right idea, but didn't put in the right spot.